# $\cos x − 2\sin x = 1$. How to solve using $R\cos(x+a)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have this question: $\cos x − 2\sin x = 1$. You have to solve for $x$, the answer being 4.069. I've tried answering but I just keep getting 2.214. This is my method:

$\cos x − 2\sin x = 1$

$R\cos(x+a)= 1$

$R = \sqrt{1^2 + (-2)^2}$

$a = \arctan(-2/1)$

therefore $\sqrt5 \cos(x - 1.107) = 1$

$\cos(x - 1.107) = \sqrt5/5$

$\arccos(\sqrt5/5) = x - 1.707$

$1.707 = x - 1.707$

therefore $x = 2.214$

Can anyone give me a hint where I'm going wrong? Thank you

Comment: you have $\cos(a)>0$ and $\sin(a)<0$ so $a$ belongs to $(-\frac{\pi}2,0)$. check that $1.107$ is in the wrong quadrant. Also if $a=-1.107$ then it should be $R\cos(x-a)=1$ not '+'.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\cos x-2\sin x&=R\cos(x+\alpha)\\[1ex]
&=R\cos x\cos\alpha-R\sin x\sin\alpha
\end{align}$$

$$\implies\begin{cases}R\cos\alpha=1\\R\sin\alpha=2\end{cases}$$

Dividing the expressions in the second equation by those in the first gives

$$\frac{R\sin\alpha}{R\cos\alpha}=\tan\alpha=2\implies \alpha=\tan^{-1}(2)+n\pi$$

(where $n\in\mathbb Z$)

Taking the squares and summing them gives

$$(R\cos\alpha)^2+(R\sin\alpha)^2=1^2+2^2\implies R^2=5\implies R=\pm\sqrt5$$

Take $R=\sqrt5$ and $n=0$, so that

$$\cos x-2\sin x=\sqrt 5\cos(x+\tan^{-1}(2))=1$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$$a=\arctan\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)$$
not
$$\arctan\left(\frac{-2}{1}\right)$$
This is because you are using $R\cos(x+a)$ as opposed to $R\cos(x-a)$.

If you need any more help, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: thank you so much :)

Comment: @georgiapage you are most welcome, I'm glad to have helped you! Are you taking A Level Maths (I am) ?

Comment: sorry about the late response but yes I am! Learning the course online because of covid isn't fun, but it is what it is I guess haha

Comment: @georgiapage so am I; were you going to be taking A Levels this year or next year?

Comment: I was supposed to take my exams this year, but obviously, that isn't happening anymore

Comment: @georgiapage right, likewise.